# How to concatenate div Id in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular5

I am working on Angular 5 app form. Inside template I need to apply div id that is concatenate with question.key (question.key value is coming via json) with "#" or @. I have apply following code but not getting result what I want??

```
<div [id]="('#'+'question.key')" class="question-block">
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution....

### Template

```
 <div [id]=assembleQuestionId(question.key) class="question-block">
```

### component

```
 assembleQuestionId(questionKey:string)
{
        return "QB_"+questionKey;  //QB (questionBlock) 
}
```